# Need to hide piece of text after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have long paragraph of text with js hiding it and showing only first 150 letters. After clicking on read more button, it shows rest of the content. My goal to reach is change "read more" link to similar "hide" button after whole text appears.

And after click on "hide" link text hiding to 150 letters and "read more" button appears again.

How can i do this with this code?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aygeyj

```
$('.review-item__text').each(function(event){ 
    var max_length = 150; 
    if($(this).html().length > max_length){ 
        var short_content = $(this).html().substr(0,max_length); 
        var long_content = $(this).html().substr(max_length);
        $(this).html(short_content+
            '<span>...</span>'+ 
            '<a href="#" class="read_more">Read more</a>'+
            '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;">'+long_content+'</span>'); 

        $(this).find('a.read_more').click(function(event){ 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).hide(); 
            $(this).parents('.review-item__text').find('.more_text').show(); 

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Change `.show()` to `.toggle()`, and change the `text()` of the "read more" link instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code out.

```
$('.review-item__text').each(function(event){ 
        var max_length = 150; 
        if($(this).html().length > max_length){ 
            var short_content = $(this).html().substr(0,max_length); 
            var long_content = $(this).html().substr(max_length);
            $(this).html(short_content+
                         '<span>...</span>'+    
                         '<a href="#" class="read_more">Read more</a>'+
                         '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;">'+long_content+'</span>'); 

            $(this).find('a.read_more').click(function(event){ 
                event.preventDefault(); 
        var more_text = $(this).parents('.review-item__text').find('.more_text');
        if(more_text.is(':visible')){
          $(this).html('Read More'); 
                $(this).parents('.review-item__text').find('.more_text').hide(); 
          $(this).appendTo($(this).parents('.review-item__text'));
        }else{

                $(this).html('Hide Extra'); 
                $(this).parents('.review-item__text').find('.more_text').show(); 
          $(this).appendTo($(this).parents('.review-item__text').find('.more_text'));
        }

            });

        }

    });
```

Working example is here 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMLddq?editors=1010

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks!